# Automatically build files before commit

Tags: git, githooks

I have a git repository with some text documents and slides (LibreOffice odt and odp files). I want to automatically convert them into pdf files, and then commit both the documents and the pdf files (so that users of my repository will not have to build the pdf files themselves).
I already wrote a simple makefile that does this conversion automatically:

```
MAKEPDF=libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf
SOURCES=$(shell find . -name '*.od*')
TARGETS=$(subst .odp,.pdf,$(subst .odt,.pdf,$(SOURCES)))

all: $(TARGETS)
    #

%.pdf: %.odt
    #
    $(MAKEPDF) $< --outdir $(@D)

%.pdf: %.odp
    #
    $(MAKEPDF) $< --outdir $(@D)
```

What I need now is to run this makefile any time I commit new changes.

I read [here](https://git-scm.com/book/uz/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) about git hooks, and thought to use the pre-commit hook. But, this hook runs after I add the files to commit, so the newly generated files will not be added.

Is there a way to automatically make all pdf files and stage them for commit?

Comment: `pre-commit` hook executes before creating the commit, so you could use a `pre-commit` hook to `1) generate files` and then `2) git add` those files. However, be aware that the generally accepted guiding principle is that you should not be committing generated files in git. See for example: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/192115
https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~mernst/advice/version-control.html#Dont_commit_generated_files

Comment: @Alderath this works, thanks